# Tableview numberOfRowsInSection returns duplicate .count number?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

This might be a really stupid question, but i can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Below is a small part code of a tableview and an empty dictionary.

```
// MARK: - Object2
struct Object2: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let url: String
    let displayname: String
    let media: [Media2]
}

// MARK: - Media2
struct Media2: Codable {
    let id, prodno: Int
    let webpath: String
    let slot: Int
    let type, extdata: String
    let ctime, xsize, ysize, mediasetid: Int
    let alt, title: String
    let generation: Int
    let created, changed: String
}


var sokresultat2 = [Object2]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(sokresultat2.count)
        return sokresultat2.count
    }
```

The "numberOfRowsInSection" func is checking the .count of the variable "sokresultat2", and it always prints out double zero, just like this:

```
0
0
```

Isn't it supposed to print out only 1 zero?

I've played around with the code, but it always prints out a duplicate of the amount, why is this? I'm simply curious to how this works.

Thanks!

Comment: To me, this isn't a stupid question. (And I don't know the answer either.) A few thoughts? First, what if you actually had data? Does it work like you'd expect? (To me this is most important.) Second, what's the value of `section`? Finally, is this some sort of zero-based issue?

Comment: @dfd Hey! Thanks for a fast reply.
If i fill the dictionary with data, it works as expected. It does print the double zeroes first, but after i've downloaded the data (API-GETrequest) and ran "self.Tableview.reloadData()", it prints out the correct .count only once. I'm not sure what you mean with the other two questions (sry, im a complete beginner). The value of section should be 0, dont think its a zero-based issue.

Comment: The data source methods are called when the tableview needs to. It is probably called initially when the tableview is instantiated and then again when your view has been laid out.  Basically, don't concern yourself with how many times it is called.

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11. There's quite a bit going on with a `UITableView`, which I believe dates back to iPhone 1 or 2007. Reusable cells are the largest thing, but it's tied into the OS so tightly for performance reasons. If it works as you want, no need for concern.

Comment: Alright, I see. Thanks for taking the time with the replies  :)

Comment: I guess you should take care of it if you can. There is no need rendering the tableview twice when you can achieve your display goals by rendering it just once. 

Have you used UITableViewController or a TableView inside a UIViewController?